# Google Map v2 getWidth in pixels

Tags: android, google-maps, width

Im just upgrading my app to Google Maps v2 and i want to get the measured width of the MapFragment or GoogleMap.
Here is what I want to do.

int mapWidth = ((View)sMapFrag_v2.getMap()).getMeasuredWidth();

How to do something like this using the new API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Woah there instantly stumbled across my answer!

```
int mapWidth =  sMapFrag_v2.getView().getMeasuredWidth()
```